# z-index doesn't work on my menu

Tags: html, css

I have a menu icon that when I click on it my list items appear;
but it pushes down other elements. I want to set my `z-index` to it hasn't any effect on other element. but it doesn't work.

```
 <div class="dropdown hidden-md hidden-lg ">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div class="dropbtn">
                <span class="bar1"></span>
                <span class="bar2"></span>
                <span class="bar3"></span>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li  class="dropdown-content">
            <ul>
               <li>خانه</li>
                <li>توانایی ها</li>
                <li> <a  href='products.php'>محصولات</a></li>
                <li><a  href='projects.php'>پروژه ها</a></li>
                <li><a  href='aboutus.php'>درباره ما</a></li>
                <li><a  href='contactus.php'>تماس با ما</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    clear: both;
    float: right;
    direction: rtl;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 75px;
    font: 1.2em Yekan;
}
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 999999999999;
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
}
```

JS

```
$(".dropbtn").on("click",
    function() {
        $(".dropdown-content").toggle();
    }
);
```

Comment: z-index works - but it's doing something different from what you want

Comment: how can i solve my problem?

Comment: It is not clear for me what you are trying to archive. Maybe you want a absolute position for `.dropdown`?

Comment: yes. it should be absolute

Comment: If you want use z-index - position must be: absolute

Comment: @QuỳnhNguyễn `z-index` can also be used on `position:relative`

Comment: @Arthur Really. I always use absolute, and z-index will be working well.

Comment: `z-index` work well with both, but `position:absolute` and `relative` are to different option (with different results).

Comment: @Arthur Really thanks sir.

Answer (score 0):

z-index is a relative property that display your index according to the order where you put your element in your page.

```
<div>here the z-index is equal to 1</div>
<div>here the z-index is equal to 2</div>
```

If you want to be sure that your z-index is take in consideration you can put an absolute position to your html element but you break the index stack of your element.

For sample in your case if you want to do that your .dropdown is still above all the other element you can do :

```
.dropdown {
position: absolute;
z-index:999999999999;
float: right;
text-align: right;
}
```

But it's will also run with a relative element position and in than case you have to be careful of teh impact because you break the "z-index stack". One advice is that case is to set all the z-index of all your element impact by your design.

Answer (score 0):

First, I put your code on embed and add some style to see your btn.
Second, I fix your bug by replacing `position:relative` by `position:absolute`

```js
$(".dropbtn").on("click", function(){
   $(".dropdown-content").toggle();
});
```

```css
/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
   display:none;
   clear: both;
   float: right;
   direction: rtl;
   background-color: #f9f9f9;
   min-width: 75px;
   font:1.2em Yekan;
}
 .dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  z-index:999999999999;
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
}
ul {
  list-style-type:none
}
.dropbtn {
  cursor:pointer;
}
.bar {
  display:block;
  height: 4px;
  width: 24px;
  background: black;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown hidden-md hidden-lg ">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="dropbtn">
        <span class="bar1 bar"></span>
        <span class="bar2 bar"></span>
        <span class="bar3 bar"></span>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li  class="dropdown-content">
      <ul>
        <li>خانه</li>
        <li>توانایی ها</li>
        <li> <a  href='products.php'>محصولات</a></li>
        <li><a  href='projects.php'>پروژه ها</a></li>
        <li><a  href='aboutus.php'>درباره ما</a></li>
        <li><a  href='contactus.php'>تماس با ما</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```